# Не могу воспользоваться PeakCAN интерфейсом в библиотеке QCanBus.

Tags: qt, qt5, can

Не могу воспользоваться PeakCAN плагином в Qt5, почему-то не видит подключенное CAN устройство (CAN-Hardware).
делал по [ссылке](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtserialbus-peakcan-overview.html)

Подключил библиотеку serialbus, создал код:

```
void MainWindow::PCAN_interface()
{
    if(QCanBus::instance()->plugins().contains(QStringLiteral("peakcan")))
    {
        qDebug() << "пикан есть";
    }

    QString errorString;
    QCanBusDevice *device = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(
                QStringLiteral("peakcan"), QStringLiteral("Port_#0003"), &errorString);

    if (!device){
        qDebug()<< errorString;
    }
    else {
        device->connectDevice();
    }
}
```

Вот что выводит :

```
пикан есть
Cannot load library pcanbasic: Не найден указанный модуль.
"Cannot load library pcanbasic: Не найден указанный модуль."
```

Перебрал все варианты имен но как то не заработало.

Я могу напрямик подключить от [производителя](https://www.peak-system.com/)    PCANBasic.dll и PCANBasic.h (проверял прекрасно работает).

НО я просто хочу узнать возможно ли работать с CAN-ом используя библиотеку QCanBus

Comment: `QCanBus::availableDevices ()` что выводит? что такое `"Port_#0003"`? По ссылке: `Note: Only the USB and PCI adapters are currently supported by this plugin.`